# (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-custom-properties in bulma css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, bulma

## Summary

I'm use Bulma CSS Framework on rails5 app with webpacker.
I got warnings like below, When I build css files as `./bin/webpack-dev-server`. Does anyone know to eliminate them?

`23:37:47 webpacker.1 |     WARNING in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/import-glob-loader!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
23:37:47 webpacker.1 |     (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-custom-properties: /some_rails_app/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:9284:3: Custom property ignored: not scoped to the top-level :root element (.columns.is-variable { ... --columnGap: ... })`

## Versions

- Rails: 5.1.4
- Bulma: 0.6.1
- Ruby: 2.4.1p111
- Webpacker: 3.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext/issues/186 on github and here's how I setup to get rid of the warnings.

**Terminal**

```
yarn add postcss-cssnext
```

Add new options to postcss-loader in **config/webpack/loaders/sass.js**

```
{
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    plugins: (loader) => [
      require('postcss-cssnext')({
        features: {
          customProperties: {
            warnings: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
},
```

Or if you are not using postcss, just remove postcss-loader and you're all set.

Comment: I'm also getting this problem.  I don't need PostCSS. How can I get rid of it? I've tried yarn removing it but it says it's not installed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to remove postcss-loader from webpack config. They've put the configurations inside a npm package now so can't change it directly. Here's the document they provide [doc](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md). Try to play around with `environment.loaders` and see if you can remove postcss-loader.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with React and webpack configuration. So I added `postcss.config.js` file and added following code:

```
const postcssCssNext = require('postcss-cssnext')
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        postcssCssNext({
            features: {
                customProperties: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            }
        }),
        postcssImport
    ]
}
```